# Can't create HR schema on Oracle 21c (SP2-0310)

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle and i'm trying to install HR schema but error occurs.
[image]
SP2-0310: unable to open file "**SUB__CWD**/human_resources/hr_cre.sql" connecting and granting seems work but this error occurs and i can't create hr schema..
I searched and tried many ways, but I couldn't find the right solution.
I'm using oracle 21c version and my OS is windows10.

I entered like this

```
sys as sysdba
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
@?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql hr users temp {password} $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log/ localhost:1521/XE
```

I tried [Installing Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-CB945E4C-D08A-4B26-A12D-3D6D688467EA) like this and [installation of the sample schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00006) like this but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you execute this before trying (it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/oracle-samples/db-sample-schemas)):
perl -p -i.bak -e 's#__SUB__CWD__#'$(pwd)'#g' *.sql */*.sql */*.dat

Comment: I ran into this exact issue in January.  Discussed [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4480957/installation-of-sample-schemas#latest)

Comment: Actually, I don't know exactly what perl is. Can I just download it and execute this command?

Comment: I solved this problem by modifying codes #__SUB__CWD__# which are in hr_make.sql to @?/demo/schema/human_resources directly using text editor. Thank you so much!